# How to add a row into groupby groups with one value change in each newly inserted row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, data-science

Lets says that I have a dataframe as below:

```
effective_date,md_code,prop_dtls
2021-03-23,comm,car
2021-03-23,comm,bike
2021-03-23,comm,scooter
2021-03-24,comm,car
2021-03-24,comm,bike
2021-03-24,comm,scooter
2021-03-12,dme,bus
2021-03-12,dme,eco
2021-03-12,dme,alto
2021-03-14,dme,bus
2021-03-14,dme,eco
2021-03-14,dme,alto
2021-03-12,equity,bus
2021-03-12,equity,eco
2021-03-12,equity,alto
2021-03-14,equity,bus
2021-03-14,equity,eco
2021-03-14,equity,alto
```

I wanted to inserted a row in each group `(groupby(by=['md_code','prop_dtls']))` with same `effective_date` and `md_code` value in the group but change in `prop_dtls` value which is also a fixed value, i.e., `'nano'`.

So my expected output should be like:

```
effective_date,md_code,prop_dtls
2021-03-23,comm,car
2021-03-23,comm,bike
2021-03-23,comm,scooter
2021-03-23,comm,nano      +added row
2021-03-24,comm,car
2021-03-24,comm,bike
2021-03-24,comm,scooter
2021-03-24,comm,nano      +added row
2021-03-12,dme,bus
2021-03-12,dme,eco
2021-03-12,dme,alto
2021-03-12,dme,nano      +added row
2021-03-14,dme,bus
2021-03-14,dme,eco
2021-03-14,dme,alto
2021-03-14,dme,nano      +added row
2021-03-12,equity,bus
2021-03-12,equity,eco
2021-03-12,equity,alto
2021-03-12,equity,nano   +added row
2021-03-14,equity,bus
2021-03-14,equity,eco
2021-03-14,equity,alto
2021-03-14,equity,nano   +added row
```

How can this be done using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `effective_data` and `md_code` columns and then use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) together with [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to add a new row to each group. Finally, use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill the NaN values in the two groupby columns.

Code:

```
g = df.groupby(['effective_date', 'md_code'])
pd.concat([i.append({'prop_dtls': 'nano'}, ignore_index=True) for _, i in g]).ffill()
```

Result:

```
  effective_date   md_code  prop_dtls
0     2021-03-12       dme        bus
1     2021-03-12       dme        eco
2     2021-03-12       dme       alto
3     2021-03-12       dme       nano
0     2021-03-12    equity        bus
1     2021-03-12    equity        eco
2     2021-03-12    equity       alto
3     2021-03-12    equity       nano
0     2021-03-14       dme        bus
1     2021-03-14       dme        eco
2     2021-03-14       dme       alto
3     2021-03-14       dme       nano
0     2021-03-14    equity        bus
1     2021-03-14    equity        eco
2     2021-03-14    equity       alto
3     2021-03-14    equity       nano
0     2021-03-23      comm        car
1     2021-03-23      comm       bike
2     2021-03-23      comm    scooter
3     2021-03-23      comm       nano
0     2021-03-24      comm        car
1     2021-03-24      comm       bike
2     2021-03-24      comm    scooter
3     2021-03-24      comm       nano
```